# BigQuery API : Ignore rows that already exist

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I want to update my BigQuery table with the Python API of BigQuery :

```
client = bigquery.Client()

project_id = "000"
dataset_id = "111"
table_id = "222"

table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    schema=table.schema,
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df,
    table_ref,
    job_config=job_config,
)

job.result()
```

This works, but using the TRUNCATE method, which deletes and replaces all the values in the table.
My table is so large that it takes too long to update it each time.

I'd like to know if it's possible to import only a smaller dataset (data of the week) that potentially includes already existing rows and update and add only the rows that don't yet exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a unique column like id. If exists you can first use something like this:

```
ids=tuple(df["id"].tolist())

delete_sql='''
DELETE from table_name WHERE id IN {};
'''.format(ids)

client.query(delete_sql)
```

Don't forget to change **WRITE_TRUNCATE** to **WRITE_APPEND**.

Or you can use [**`ScalarQueryParameter:`**](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.query.ScalarQueryParameter)

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

sql="DELETE from table_name WHERE id IN (@ids)"
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(
            "ids","STRING",tuple(df["id"].tolist()))])
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
```